# Why is the trace of such a simplicial map is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

Given simplicial complexes $K,L$, a map $f:K\to L$ is simplicial if it sends each simplex of $K$ to a simplex of $L$ by a linear map taking vertices to vertices, which means it has form: $\sum_{i}t_i v_i \to \sum_{i} t_i f(v_i)$, where $v_i$ denotes vertex and each $t_i$ is a number.

Now, since $H_n(K)$ and $H_n(L)$ are free abelian groups, we can talk about the trace of induced map on the torsion free part of the groups $f_*: H_n(K)/Torsion \to H_n(L)/Torsion$.

In Hatcher’s, he says that if a simplicial map $g$ satisfies $g(\sigma)\cap \sigma =\emptyset$ for all simplex in $K$, then the matrix for $g_*$ has zeros down the diagonal, thus has trace zero.

I don’t know why this statement holds? If we see vertices as a base since $g$ is a linear map on vertices, it becomes a linear algebra question. But I can’t go further. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: How is the induced map on homology defined? Are you using simplicial or singular homology?

Comment: Could you provide a reference for where he says this? You can only take traces of a map from a space into itself, and I believe there must be more conditions because if you give the circle a simplicial structure by splitting it into 4 line segments, we may rotate the circle and obtain a map satisfying your condition that is homotopic to the identity. This map has trace 1.

Comment: If you have a finite simplicial complex on $K$, then the chain complex $C_n(K)$ is given by the span of all $n$-simplices as abstract generators. If a simplicial map $g:K\to K$ satisfies $g(\sigma)\cap\sigma=\emptyset$ for all $\sigma$ then the map induced by $g$ on $C_n(K)$ must send the basis vector $\sigma$ to a linear combination of the _other_ basis vectors. In particular $\widetilde{\sigma}( g_*(\sigma))=0$ where $\widetilde\sigma$ is the "dual" of $\sigma$. Since the trace of $g_*$ is $\sum_{\sigma \text{ $n$ simplex}}\widetilde\sigma(g_*(\sigma))$ you get that the trace is $0$.

Comment: @s.harp This is on the chain complex level though. You may get nonzero trace in the homology. For example, the map swapping $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ has trace 0, but when restricting to the diagonal and making the trivial quotient, it has trace $1$.

Comment: @Connor thanks, looks like I got a bit confused. But as you remark the statement is false for homology. Rotating the circle $S^1$ is an example where the induced map on homology is the identity but you can choose a simplicial complex so that the condition $g(\sigma)\cap\sigma=\emptyset$ is satisfied.

Comment: @ConnorMalin His statement comes from additional topic in chapter two about Lefschetz fixed point theory, in book Algebraic Topology.

Comment: I missed some rather important information. The induced map is defined as $g_*: H_n(K^n, K^{n-1})\to H_n(K^n, K^{n-1})$.

Comment: Homology groups of simplicial complexes are in general not free abelian (as you claim).

Comment: $g(\sigma) \cap \sigma = \emptyset$ only makes sense if $K = L$. Moreover, I think that you consider finite complexes. In that case homology groups are finitely generated, and you can introduce the trace on the torsion free parts. I strongly recommend to clarify these points by editing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some context: the question refers to Hatcher's proof of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem. The proof goes like this: Given a finite simplicial complex $X$, he wants to show that if some map $f:X \to X$ has no fixed points, then $\tau(f_*) = 0$. He does this by constructing a map $g$, homotopic to $f$, which is simplicial when considered as a map from some subdivision $K$ of $X$ to itself, such that $g(\sigma) \cap \sigma = \emptyset$ for all simplices $\sigma$ in this subdivision. He further shows that the Lefschetz number $\tau(f)$ can be computed by
$$
\tau(f) = \tau(g) = \sum (-1)^n \text{tr} \left( g_*: H_n(K_n, K_{n-1}) \to H_n(K_n, K_{n-1})\right)
$$
Then he claims that each summand on the right side is zero. This is what the question is asking about. The group $H_n(K_n, K_{n-1})$ is free abelian, with basis the $n$-simplices of $K$, and the map $g_*: H_n(K_n, K_{n-1}) \to H_n(K_n, K_{n-1})$ will take the generator for an $n$-simplex $\sigma$ to (up to a sign) the generator for the simplex $g(\sigma)$, or to zero if $g(\sigma)$ is not $n$-dimensional. So since $g(\sigma) \cap \sigma$ is empty, the matrix for $g_*$ has zeroes down the diagonal.

Comment: Hi @John. First, Kudos for giving the context so concise and clear. I didn't quite understand the conclusion. If $g(\sigma)\cap\sigma=\emptyset$, then there are no common vertices for $g(\sigma)$ and $\sigma$. So how does it say anything about $g_\ast$ and particularly how does it say anything about the diagonal of $g_\ast$'s matrix?

Comment: The $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix for $g_*$ will be nonzero iff $g$ takes simplex $i$ to simplex $j$. Since $g$ never takes a simplex to itself, the diagonal entries are therefore all zero.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I think I spotted my problem: "The $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix for $g_*$ will be nonzero iff $g$ takes simplex $i$ to simplex $j$". I can't see why this holds.. The matrix for $g_*$ operates on a vector of vertices, representing a simplex. So multiplying __the whole matrix__ by this vector will produce a new simplex. How does it coincide with the quote? I know I'm missing something basic..

Comment: The map $g_*$ has as domain and codomain $H_n(K_n, K_{n-1})$, which is free abelian with basis the $n$-simplices of $K$. So the rows and columns for the matrix representing $g_*$ with respect to this basis are indexed by the $n$-simplices of $K$.

Comment: Note that the matrix for $g_*$ does not operate on a "vector of vertices". Its domain (and codomain) is free abelian on the $n$-simplices of $K$, so I guess you could say it operates on a "vector of $n$-simplices".

Comment: Sorry for the length. The (probably wrong) way I see it: Let $\sigma=\sum_i{c_i\sigma_i}$ where $\sigma_i$ is represented by the i-th basis vector for $H_n(K_n,K_{n-1})$. Then $g(\sigma)\neq\sigma\Leftrightarrow g(\sum_i{c_i\sigma_i})\neq \sum_i{c_i\sigma_i}\Leftrightarrow \sum_i{c_i g(\sigma_i)\sum_i{c_i\sigma_i}}\Leftrightarrow g(\sigma_i)\neq\sigma_i$.

Comment: So:  
$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{12}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow a_{11}b_1+a_{12}b_2\neq b_1$, where $\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}$ is the vector representing $\sigma_i$, and the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{12}\end{bmatrix}$ representing $g_*$.

Why $a_{11}b_1+a_{12}b_2\neq b_1$ means $a_{11}=0$?

Comment: $g(\sigma) \cap \sigma = \emptyset$ for all $\sigma$. For example, $g(\sigma_1) \cap \sigma_1 = \emptyset$. Therefore the $(1,1)$-entry of the matrix for $g_*$ is zero. (In fact, since $g$ is simplicial, $g$ will take $\sigma_1$ to a single $n$-simplex or to a lower-dimensional simplex, so $g_*$ will take $\sigma_1$ to $\pm \sigma_j$ for some $j \neq 1$, or to zero. I'm abusing notation in this part, using $\sigma_1$ to refer both to the simplex and the corresponding generator in the homology group.)