# The $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix for $g_∗$ will be nonzero iff $g$ takes simplex $i$ to simplex $j$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Regarding the answer in the following link:
[Why is the trace of such a simplicial map is zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321892/why-is-the-trace-of-such-a-simplicial-map-is-zero/3322336?noredirect=1#comment7322662_3322336)
(The answer gives great background for the question).

I asked @John Palmieri a follow up question and he answered:

> The $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix for $g_∗$ will be nonzero iff $g$ takes simplex $i$ to simplex $j$

How do you prove this claim?

Comment: Did you read the last two sentences of John's answer ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the part I don't understand in the proof for Lefschetz theorem.