# If $g$ is a simplicial map of a finite simplicial complex $X$, then the diagonal of the matrix of $g_*:H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})\to (X^n,X^{n-1})$ is zero

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

Let $X$ be a finite simplical complex, and let $g:X\to X$ be a continuous simplicial map such that $g(\sigma)\cap \sigma=\emptyset$ for every simplex $\sigma $ in $X$. Then why is the diagonal of the matrix of the map $g_*:H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})\to (X^n,X^{n-1})$ is zero? (This question is from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. Hatcher uses this statement in the proof of Lefschetz's fixed point theorem(Theorem 2C.3), but I can't see why this is true.)

First, I know that since $g$ is simplicial, we have $g(X^n)\subset X^n$ for all $n$, so $g$ induces a map $g_*:H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})\to H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})$. Also, I know that $H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})$ is free abelian with basis corresponding to the $n$-cells of $X$. But I can't see how the result follows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can "Geometrically" see it as follows: $H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})$ may as well be thought of as $H_n(\vee_{i=1}^k S^n)$. Then the map is a map from $\mathbb Q^k \to \mathbb Q^k$. If it  had a diagonal nonzero entry then it would be a map of that copy of $S^n$ to itself.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321892/why-is-the-trace-of-such-a-simplicial-map-is-zero/3322336?noredirect=1#comment7326187_3322336

Comment: What do you mean by "$H_n(X^n, X^{n-1}) \to (X^n, X^{n-1})$"? Is the target of $g_*$ meant to also be $H_n(X^n, X^{n-1})$?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thanks

Comment: @William Thanks. I've corrected it.